# How can I put two input elements side by side in the Contact Form 7?

Tags: css, wordpress, contact-form-7

I have a contact form in my WordPress website that I made using Contact Form 7 and I want it to look exactly like this form in the below image:[The contact form style i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/afL8H.png)

Below also the CSS code that I used to style this form:

```css
div.wpcf7 { 
/*background-color: #fbefde;*/
text-align:center;
color: white;
align-items: center;
}
.wpcf7 input[type="text"],
.wpcf7 input[type="email"],
.wpcf7 textarea {
text-align: center;
background-color: #fefefe;
border-color: #efefef;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;     
}
.wpcf7 input[type="submit"],
.wpcf7 input[type="button"] { 
background-color: #fc5f45;
color: #ffffff;
font-family: "Poppins", Sans-serif;
font-size: 16px;
font-weight: 500;
line-height: 50px;
border-radius: 30px 30px 30px 30px;
padding: 0px 40px 0px 40px;
}
```

But i want two input elements to be on the same line and not just one as in the image below:

[The actual contact form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lcD32.png)

Comment: There are two ways you can achieve what you want, either wrapping your fields inside custom HTML and then applying CSS to them or using css giving `widths`. Can you pl. replicate your issue here or share URL?

Comment: I can give the input fields a class name but how can achieve this styling using CSS?

Comment: Is your theme using bootstrap or some other framework? Or you don't know.  You wrap the `[text]` form tags in a `<div>` that is how you do it.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your CSS:

```
body .wpcf7 input[type="text"],
body .wpcf7 input[type="email"] {
width: 49%;
}

body .wpcf7 input[type="text"]:nth-child(even),
body .wpcf7 input[type="email"]:nth-child(even) {
    float: left;
    clear: left;
}

body .wpcf7 input[type="text"]:nth-child(odd),
body .wpcf7 input[type="email"]:nth-child(odd) {
    float: right;
    clear: right;
}
```

Note, this will only work assuming your inputs are not wrapped inside other elements, if so, you need to change the selectors above to match the wrapper of each input.